# Blocking all apps from using internet on Windows

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking

I've searched through some threads here, yet I still not have an answer to my question. Basically, I have some weird internet connection, which is really sensitive on any usage and it's not unlimited. I bought 50GB extra monthly internet to play some games on normal ping. I want to minimize the use of data (I've already selected "set as metered connection" in network settings) and the general use of that connection (so my ping doesn't go nuts). I realized that I have to actually search for apps using the internet in Task manager and then turn them off separately.

My question here is: Is there a way to do this automatically? Like I select every app, or I select them all and unselect only those I want to use, I press a button, and then magic happens, they cannot use my connection? Or do I have to do this manually?

Comment: Well, yeah. But I want an ON/OFF switch, a quick solution. Not manually blocking apps, and then unblocking them if I switch to my normal internet connection

Comment: Then disable the network interface when you don't want the connection.

Comment: As @Biswapriyo suggests, use Airplane Mode - an easy click to the taskbar.

Comment: What you want can only be accomplished by using Third-Party applications.  While you could block a program, in Windows Firewall, that would block it.  Which would require you to remove the rule, each time, you wanted it to access the internet.  Outside of doing that, what you want, cannot be accomplished without a third-party application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up your rules on on Windows Firewall, and export them and also import.

What you can do is to save the firewall rules for the two states :

- Normal state, most connections are allowed
- Restricted state, where everything is blocked except for some chosen applications.

Saving your rules is done in the Windows Defender Firewall with Advance Security,
using the menu option *Action / Export Policy ...*

Restoring them is done by the menu *Action / Import Policy ...*

[image]

You may also do the same via PowerShell :

```
netsh advfirewall export "C:\temp\WFconfiguration.wfw"  
netsh advfirewall import "C:\temp\WFconfiguration.wfw"
```